# Set default properties in base class from derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Ok so, I've run into an interested and probably simple problem.  I have a base class that is inherited by another class (child).  I have the same parameterless constructor in the base and the child.  I would like to set defaults in the child that propagate into the base properties.  I would like to do something like this:

```
public partial class baseclass
{
    public baseclass() {
        //never called if instantiated from baseclass(string newp1)
        p1 = "";
        p2 = "google";
    }

    public baseclass(string newp1) {
        p1 = newp1; //p2 will be "" and p1 will be newP1
    }

    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
}

public partial class childclass : baseclass
{
    public childclass() { 
        //How can I call this to set some default values for the child?
        p2 = "facebook";
    }

    public childclass(string newp1) : base(newp1) {
        p1 = newp1; //p2 needs to be "facebook"
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not inheriting nothing. To inherit you do `public class child : base`. [Partial classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) are totally different thing.

Comment: `public class childclass: baseclass`

Comment: My bad, I missed that when I added the example but it is in my local code.

Answer (score 1):

Use constructors chaining if you have duplicated code in several constructors:

```
public class baseclass
{
    public baseclass() : this("google") { }
    public baseclass(string newp1)
    {
       p1 = newp1; // the only place in your code where you init properties
       p2 = "";
    }

    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
}
```

Child class should inherit baseClass

```
public class childclass : baseclass
{
    public childclass() : this("facebook") { } // you can also call base here
    public childclass(string newp1) : base(newp1) { }
}
```

Also keep in mind that `parital` just allows you split class/method definiton in several parts (e.g. keep it in different files). It is useful when you are generating classes (e.g. from database tables) but still want to add/customize something in generated classes. If you will put customized code directly into generated files, then it will be lost after classes re-generation. [Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Sergey! I'll give these a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protected constructor in base class and call it in child class:

```
    public class Base
    {
       public Base(int value1, int value2) { ... }
       protected Base(string value1) { ... } // only for child class
    }

    public class Child : Base
    {
       public Child() : Base("Value") { ... }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I think I'm moving in the right direction.  Much appreciated Mateusz!